# Como pasar un entero a un JDialog

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una agenda con interfaz gráfica.
Tengo los paquetes controlador, vista y modelo.
Vista y marco solo se relacionan por el controlador.
EN este momento tengo el marco que presenta el panel de un contacto con sus datos digamos básicos, pero resuelta que un contacto puede tener
muchos departamentos y por lo tanto muchos teléfonos, digamos por ejemplo 20. Como no me caben en el panel del contacto, el cual muestro
por medio del controlador y sigo en el mismo controlador con

```
Mapa<String,Depart> mapa=contacto.getDeparts();   
Set<String> claves=mapa.keySet();
int size=claves.size(); //estos datos varían según cada contacto
Depart[] dep=new Depart[size];
int i=0;
for(String s:claves){
    dep[i]=mapa.get(s);
    i++;
}
```

Entonces por medio del mismo panel de contacto, pulsando un botón MAS, muestro un JDialog donde muestro todos los teléfonos que pueda tener el contacto.
O sea, en pantalla estoy viendo el panel contacto y abro el JDialog para ver todos los telefonos que no me caben en el panel contacto. Pero
para este JDialog necesito obtener el size. Mediante el size podré determinar las líneas: paneles de una linea con labels y textfields
(1 principal 65265236 juan@gmail.com)
(2 movil      565286  juan@outlook.es),
etc. dependiendo del tamaño del map.

getObjM().getDialogCM() → AQUÍ ES DONDE ME ENCUENTRO CON EL PROBLEMA

No sé como el JDiagog puede obtener este size sin cambiar el constructor que es

```
public DialogContactoMas(Marco_base m){
    super(m);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane=(JPanel)this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Añadir componentes  
    contentPane.add(addComponents(6),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    pack();
}

public JPanel addComponents(int n){
    t=new JPanel[n];
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,1));
    for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        panel.add(obtenerDpto());
        t[i]=obtenerDpto();
    }
    return panel;
}

public JPanel obtenerDpto(){
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,8));
    tfCodigo=new JTextField(3);
    tfDpto=new JTextField(5);
    tfTelefono=new JTextField(10);
    tfCorreoE=new JTextField(15);
    panel.add(new PanelConLabel("Código: ",tfCodigo));
    panel.add(new PanelConLabel("Dept.: ",tfDpto));
    panel.add(new PanelConLabel("Teléfono: ",tfTelefono));
    panel.add(new PanelConLabel("Correo E.: ",tfCorreoE));       
    return panel;
}
```

Estoy bloqueado. A ver si me alguien me puede echar una mano de información.
Toda esta complicación al fin y al cabo sirve para aprender.
Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera.
En principio no queria modificar el constructor del DialogContactoMas porque tenía ya como propietario al Marco. Entonces, cosniderando
la posiblidad de crearlo sin propietario según el primer constructor de JDialog, así lo he hecho pero he tenido que añadirlo como
parámetro al Controlador.
Del controlador heredan, por una parte el ActionControlador donde en el método del ActionPerformed he puesto

```
if(getObjM().getPc().getBtMas()==boton){
        getObjDcm().setVisible(true);
    }
```

con el ActionListener para dicho botón MAS.
Por otra parte también hereda del COntrolador el MouseControlador donde al pulsar sobre un registro de la tabla me cargaba el panelContacto ya
al que he añadido tras el código anteriormente indicado:

```
getObjDcm().addComponents(size);
```

y modificando en el DialogContactoMas lo siguiente:

```
public DialogContactoMas(){
    super();     
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane=(JPanel)this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Añadir componentes 
           
}

public void addComponents(int n){
    t=new JPanel[n];
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,1));
    for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        panel.add(obtenerDpto());
        t[i]=obtenerDpto();
    }
    contentPane.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
}
```

CON ESTO HE RESUELTO MI PRETENSIÓN INDICADA AUNQUE CREO QUE NO HA SIDO UNA RESOLUCIÓN DEL TODO ORTODOXA. DESPUÉS YA VERÉ COMO RESUELVO LA CONTNUACIÓN DE MI CÓDIGO.
Gracias y saludos.